# 500 Exception when trying to download from S3 with Spring in Java

Tags: java, spring, amazon-s3

I successfully uploaded a file to S3, and I can download that file manually. When I try to do this through code, I get:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: resource loaded through InputStream cannot be resolved to URL
```

Here is my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity downloadFile(@RequestHeader("path") String fileName) throws IOException, ServiceException {
    try {
        S3Object s3Object = s3Service.downloadFile(fileName);

        InputStream objectInputStream = s3Object.getObjectContent();
        InputStreamResource is = new InputStreamResource(objectInputStream);

        String newFileName = URLEncoder.encode(s3Object.getKey(), "UTF-8").replaceAll("\\+", "%20");

        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"));
        httpHeaders.add("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + newFileName);

        return new ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>(is, httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

However, if I try to return it as a byte[] instead of as an InputFileStreamResource, I get a 200 from the server (i.e., the file is indeed found), BUT I cannot open the file downloaded, as the computer says it appears to be damaged. When I inspect the file, I see it is the SAME SIZE as the file uploaded.

Any help would be great, thanks!